# custom signup in devise gem ROR throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, rails-routing

When I am clicking on a button and passing it to the path of custom signin It is throwing an error that.

> Routing Error
>   No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"

But in the rake routes..It is present as ..

> /users/sign_up(.:format)  devise/registrations#new

Guide to get over to this error.

Comment: in your routes, it's probably listed as a GET route (to get the signup form). We need the code for what is raising the error.

Comment: Post whole line from rake routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a possibility that You have to make a custom_redirection.rb in which you have to handle the routes.
You can take help from
https://railsforum.com/topic/889-trick-devise-gem-custom-redirect-for-failed-login/
Hope this may help you!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably be using `button_to` in place `link_to` or you passed `:method => :post` with `link_to`. If you are using `button_to` then you need to specify `:method => :get` as `button_to` takes `post` method by default. Use any of the two

```
link_to "Sign Up", "/users/sign_up"
```

or

```
button_to "Sign Up", "/users/sign_up", :method => :get
```